# How to suppress warning - Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: android, react-native, asynchronous

I'm testing my React Native app on an android simulator. I'm following the advice of a React Blog writer, Jim Sproch, to [cancel](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) `setState` with a rejected promise after calling `cancel` on the promise in `componentWillUnmount`. I modified the code slightly to accept a function and not a promise:

```
export const makeCancelableFunction = (fn) => {
    let hasCanceled = false;

    return {
        promise: (val) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (hasCanceled) {
                reject({isCanceled: true});
            } else {
                fn(val);
                resolve(val);
            }
        }),
        cancel() {
            hasCanceled = true;
        }
    };
};
```

The parameter, `fn`, is a function that will set state. I get a warning message that way I use it, if and only if the promise is rejected from `makeCancelableFunction`:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
```

Here is how I use the function:

```
    this.maybeSetHistory = makeCancelableFunction((results) => {
        this.setState({
            history: results,
        });
    });
/* code hidden */
        }).then((results) => {
            this.maybeSetHistory.promise(results);
        }).catch((reason) => {
            this.props.errorCallback(reason);
        });
```

I test the code as it is used in the promise chain by exiting the view immediately after navigating to the view. When the function, `maybeSetHistory`, is called the warning message appears. I clearly don't want this to happen on actual phones.

I have tried the suggested code which takes and wraps a parameter of type, `Promise`. I have tried to toggle `production` mode, then restarting the phone emulator app, `Expo` by swiping the `Expo` app away on the emulator, toggling the mode to `production` on `Packager`, then press `a` for Android emulation. When `production` is the mode of `Packager`; nonetheless, the warning appears. Is there a way to suppress this particular warning message? Should I be concerned? Am I handling `Promise` rejections incorrectly?